# On, at, in that same night

Tags: word-choice, difference

**On that same night.**

**At that same night.**

**In that same night**  the detective had seen the suspect.

Apparently "on" is the better option, but why? They seem to carry the same meaning to me. Help, please, and thanks in advance!

Comment: We use _at night_ to mean _after dark_, but for some reason we don't say _at that night_. _In the night_ also implies _during the hours of darkness_, while _on that night_ could be _that evening._

Answer (score 2):

Preposition uses are sometimes more customary than logical. Here are some examples of idiomatic choices:

on the same day
on the same night
on that occasion
the thief came in/during the night
at five o'clock the same day
during the day/night
in/at that instant
in/at that moment
at that time
in that time (different meaning)
in/during that year
"Once upon a time..."  (fixed phrase, don't use unless you're telling a story).

For your particular example, you can avoid a preposition entirely:
"That same night, several things happened."

As to your question "why" this preposition or that, I don't think there's an answer, except in comparisons to similar uses.